# bash script ending abruptly after killing the process

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that monitors whether a process is running. The process has multiple sub-processes that are running as well.

I check whether the process is running successfully by counting whether the all the process and the sub-processes are running. If the count does not match, I attempt to kill all the processes and restart the process again.

```
#!/bin/bash
procno=$(pgrep -f process_name | wc -l);
echo  "process found: $procno"
if [ "$procno" = "4" ];then
  echo "Process is Running. No action taken"
else
  echo "Killing Processes"
  pgrep -f process_name | xargs kill
  echo "Restarting Process"
  nohup process_name &
fi
```

However, the script quits after the kill command. It does not want to restart the process. There are no error messages on the prompt but it does not restart the process nor does it execute the `echo "Restarting Process"` line.

Comment: You really have a process named `"process_name"`?

Comment: no. I changed it because I did not want to reveal the process because it is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Use a real process supervision system. `systemctl restart process_name` (once you've created `process_name.service`) -- or `sv restart process_name` with runit, or `launchctl stop process_name` with launchd, or so on and so forth -- avoids a very large set of issues associated with set of practices.

Comment: OK, just making sure you were not missing something simple like using a variable like `"$process_name"`.

Comment: Did you happen to name the script above something like `check_process_name` to where your pgrep catches the monitoring script and returns 5 instead of 4?